# FirstName field Validations in Android Studio

Tags: android, validation, android-studio, android-edittext

[Sample code format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snEfB.png)

Hello everyone, I have added this line of code for validation to check whether the first name field contains numbers or special characters however, upon testing it it seems the firstname always shows error 
can anyone pls help. big thanks!

```
    (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        showSweetDialog(AppConstants.ERR_CONNECTION, "error", false, null, null);
    }   else if (firstName.isEmpty()) {
        setError(etFirstName, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    } 

   else if(!firstName.matches("[a-zA-Z]")){
        setError(etFirstName, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    } 


else if (lastName.isEmpty()) {
        setError(etLastName, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    }  else if (mobile.isEmpty()) {
        setError(etMobile, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    } else if (email.isEmpty()) {
        setError(etEmail, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
        setError(etPassword, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    }  else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        setError(etEmail, AppConstants.WARN_INVALID_EMAIL_FORMAT);
    } else if (address.isEmpty()) {
        setError(etAddress, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
    } else {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

specify where the beginning and the end of the string is by adding ^ and $. Try it like that:

```
else if(!firstName.matches("^[A-Za-z]+$")){
    setError(etFirstName, AppConstants.WARN_FIELD_REQUIRED);
}
```

which means:

```
^           beginning of the string,
[A-Za-z]    search for alphabetical chars either they are CAPITALS or not
+           string contains at least one alphabetical char
$           end of the string
```

Now you should get the error message only if the first name contains some special or numerical characters.

Comment: and if you want only the first letter to be an Upper case instead of [A-Za-z] use [A-Z][a-z]

Comment: Got my problem fixed. Thank you sir :)

Comment: I am from react-native world. The regEx helped me out. Thanks